# matplotlib overlay a normal distribution with stddev axis onto another plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a series of data that I'm reading in from a tutorial site.
I've managed to plot the distribution of the TV column in that data, however I also want to overlay a normal distribution curve with StdDev ticks on a second x-axis (so I can compare the two curves). I'm struggling to work out how to do it..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

# read data into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)

# draw distribution curve
h = sorted(data.TV)
hmean = np.mean(h)
hstd = np.std(h)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(h, hmean, hstd)
plt.plot(h, pdf)
```

Here is a diagram close to what I'm after, where x is the StdDeviations. All this example needs is a second x axis to show the values of data.TV

[image: example image]

Comment: I've updated the question to show an example image, which should make things clearer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, assuming that you want to plot the distribution of your data, the fitted normal distribution with two x-axes, one way to achieve this is as follows.

Plot the **normalized** data together with the standard normal distribution. Then use `matplotlib`'s `twiny()` to add a second x-axis to the plot. Use the same tick positions as the original x-axis on the second axis, but scale the labels so that you get the corresponding original `TV` values. The result looks like this:

[image]

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

# read data into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Advertising.csv', index_col=0)

h = sorted(data.TV)
hmean = np.mean(h)
hstd = np.std(h)
h_n = (h - hmean) / hstd
pdf = stats.norm.pdf( h_n )

# plot data
f,ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.hist( h_n, 20, normed=1 )
ax1.plot( h_n , pdf, lw=3, c='r')
ax1.set_xlim( [h_n.min(), h_n.max()] )
ax1.set_xlabel( r'TV $[\sigma]$' )
ax1.set_ylabel( r'Relative Frequency')

ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.grid( False )
ax2.set_xlim( ax1.get_xlim() )
ax2.set_ylim( ax1.get_ylim() )
ax2.set_xlabel( r'TV' )

ticklocs = ax2.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
ticklocs = [ round( t*hstd + hmean, 2) for t in ticklocs ]
ax2.xaxis.set_ticklabels( map( str, ticklocs ) )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see the example in the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really want, but you could probably use second axis like this

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import math

# read data into a DataFrame
data = pd.read_csv('Advertising.csv', index_col=0)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# draw distribution curve
h = sorted(data.TV)
ax1.plot(h,'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('TV')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count', color='b')
for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('b')

hmean = np.mean(h)
hstd = np.std(h)
pdf = stats.norm.pdf(h, hmean, hstd)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(h, pdf, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('pdf', color='r')
for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels():
    tl.set_color('r')

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see the example in the updated question